# java.util.EmptyStackException run time error

Tags: java, stack

This EmptyStackException continues to pop up. I am unable to find where is the issue occurring in this code. It displays a run time error  "java.util.EmptyStackException" everytime. I am supposed to add to the input array A. For e.g. If A={1,2,3}, I am supposed to return {1,2,4}. Input can have 0 before MSB but output cannot.

```
public class Solution {
    public ArrayList<Integer> plusOne(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        int i,n,flag;
        flag=0;
        n=A.size();
        ArrayList<Integer> result=new ArrayList<>();
        Stack<Integer> s=new Stack<>();
        if(A.get(n-1)!=9)
        {
            s.push(A.get(n-1)+1);
            for(i=n-2;i>=0;i--)
            s.push(A.get(i));
        }
        else 
        {
            for(i=n-1;i>=0;i--)
            {
                if(A.get(i)==9)
                s.push(0);
                else 
                {s.push(A.get(i)+1);
                i--;
                break;}
            }
            for(i=i;i>=0;i--)
            {
                s.push(A.get(i));
                flag=1;
            }
            if(flag==0&&(i!=-1))
            s.push(1);
}
        while(true)
        {
            if(s.peek()==0)
           {
               s.pop();
           }
            else
            {
              break;
            }
        }
        while(true)
        {
            if(s.isEmpty())
            break;
            result.add(s.pop());
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `while(true) {if(s.peek()==0)` you're never checking whether there's actually something in the stack, so sooner or later that `peek` is gonna throw.

Comment: Anyway, when you get an exception you also get where in the code it's happening. That's something you may want to share when you ask such a question.

Comment: The exception is occuring in the this line "if(s.peek()==0)"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code of the peek function in the Stack implementation of Java.

```
public synchronized E peek() {
    int var1 = this.size();
    if (var1 == 0) {
        throw new EmptyStackException();
    } else {
        return this.elementAt(var1 - 1);
    }
}
```

You can see that if the size of the stack is zero, it is throwing an Empty Stack Exception. You need to check the size first before calling the peek method. Your stack might have no element. It might be due to your logic above. You can check if the stack is empty or not by calling the method isEmpty on the stack. If not, then you can call the peek method, or else it will throw and EmptyStackException.

```
if(!s.isEmpty() && s.peek()==0)
       {
           s.pop();
       }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks. That worked! But I still don't get it why it is returning an empty array when A=[9,9,9,9,9]

Comment: Because you keep popping stuff inside an infinite loop without checking, so it does not throw at the first iteration, but *after* you popped all the other 9s.

Comment: @TanyaAgarwal you need to debug or dry run your values to see why it is returning empty. Please select this answer if it helped you solve the emptyStackException problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that without a `Stack`.

```
static List<Integer> plusOne(List<Integer> list) {
    int size = list.size();
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(size + 1);
    int carry = 1;
    for (int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        int digit = list.get(i) + carry;
        result.add(0, digit % 10);
        carry = digit / 10;
    }
    if (carry > 0)
        result.add(0, carry);
    return result;
}
```

and

```
List<Integer> result = plusOne(List.of(9,9,9,9));
System.out.println(result);
```

output

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Hey that's a much cleaner and easier approach. I'm actually new to this.